# Unable to access sdcard

Tags: android, eclipse, io, sd-card

I'm trying to read/write files to the sdcard. I've tried doing this both on my real phone and on an emulator in eclipse. On both devices the permission to the /mnt/sdcard/ or /sdcard is only "d--------", which I guess means I can't read or write.

I cant open the folder from the "File view" in eclipse, and also when I also try the "adb pull /mnt/sdcard/test.txt test.txt" I get the remote object does not exist.

The android app does have the permission to "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Here's for example what I do when running the app;

```
        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.e(TAG,root.getAbsolutePath());
                File gpxfile = new File(root, "test.txt");
                FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
                out.write("Hello world");
                out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I do not get an exception. 
Any ideas? This problem is killing me!

Comment: `I can't read or write` you are right you have not permission read and write i also face same problem. at that time i was not able to store in emulator but store in phone device. i think there are some thing wron with path let me see preivos and give you solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example where you can show image in sdcard from perticular url so you need permission like ...

permission ::

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Java file ::

```
package com.sdcard;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class SdcardActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try{
            URL url = new URL ("http://www.coolpctips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/top-30-android-games.jpg");
            InputStream input = url.openStream();
            try {
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream  (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/top-30-android-games.jpg");
                int aReasonableSize = 1000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];
                int bytesRead = 0;;
                try {
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } finally {
                    output.close();
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**And some time also face problem in device that our Internet connection missed or we cant able to find sdcard**